# How can I call a text for imitation in a Typing speed test?

Tags: phrase-requests

I try to describe how typing speed test works and I don't know how to call a text that users should type in a special area as fast as they can. Is it "text pattern" or "text example" or "text for imitation" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it the *source text*. There are [lots of hits](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q="touch+typing"+"source+text") for this usage on Google.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinion and the link. I found that there is more than 1 variant. "test text" and "sample text" are also acceptable variants.